# Downloading QGIS 3.4. for Mac?

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

I'm trying to download QGIS 3.4. for mac. However web site says version 3.4., link name and downloaded version is still 3.2.x.

Anybody has to some issue? Do I anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Windows and Ubuntu/Debian contain the latest QGIS 3.4, however, for Mac OS, you need to wait until the package getting ready. You can refer to the [QGIS blog](http://blog.qgis.org/2018/10/28/qgis-3-4-madeira-is-released/) for more information:

> Windows installers and Ubuntu/debian binaries are already out, and all
>   the packagers are actively preparing packages for the other operating
>   systems. We’ll keep you updated when different packages and installers
>   become available.